# Failed to load module when script called by webapp, perfectly running when running from cli

Tags: php, ubuntu, imagemagick

I have a web app that uses MVC(yii2) running on Ubuntu/lampp. When the script attempts to run the identify method .
It returns nothing, but the error_log is having some lines stating the fact that a module is missing. This error is only on PNG image format, on JPEG/JPG it runs perfectly.

Already tried reinstalling imagemagick and identify, but no result. Also the script is running perfectly when called from the command line.

The model function( getFullPath returns the correct value, it's not the problem here)

```
public function identify()
{
        $cmd = "identify -verbose " . $this->getFullPath();
        $cmd = str_replace(['(', ')'], ['\\(', '\\)'], $cmd);
        exec($cmd, $o);
        return $o;   
}
```

The script that runs perfectly(it's just a png downloaded from google, my files are not saved there)

```
<?php   
$cmd = "identify -verbose /home/timurmengazi/Downloads/O-Academy-rgbrev.png";
exec($cmd, $o);
print_r($o);
?>
```

Also, the lines from error_log

```
identify-im6.q16: unable to load module `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.7//modules-Q16/coders/png.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1302.
identify-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
identify: unable to load module `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.9.7//modules-Q16/coders/png.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1302.
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
```

I am using this command to get image metadata, like compression type, quality of compression and other stuff.

Comment: Is libpng installed as a delegate? Does it list png when doing `convert -version`.

Comment: It does... `bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib`

Comment: Perhaps a conflict? Might you have more than one version of libpng on your system? Perhaps ImageMagick was installed with a libpng version that no longer exists and a new version of libpng was installed afterwards. Does `convert logo: logo.png` work? If so, then does `convert logo.png logo.gif` work?

Comment: Yes, the above commands work.

Comment: found out where the problem was, apparently doing
`sudo mv /opt/lampp/lib/libz.so.1 /opt/lampp/lib/libz.so.1.old`
followed by
`sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1` in the /opt/lampp/lib directory did the trick...dunno why to be honest.